# Does the scaled down large drawables result in final apk size and RAM usage?

Tags: android, svg, apk, android-vectordrawable

I wonder is there any difference between two `24dp x 24dp` vector drawables one with coordinates range between 0 to 24 and another with coordinates range between 0 to 2400 and with appropriate view height and view width?

I mean, does it affect the final apk size and the RAM/CPU usage of smartphone?